# Extra bytes with 2s complement

Tags: c

I'm getting a lot of extra bytes when I find the twos complement of a byte.

for example "eb" turns into "ffffff15".  When I printf this, it's -235, not -21 like I would expect it to be.

```
//unsigned char a[] holds bytes
int b=(int)a[i];
bit1=(b & 0x80 ? 1 : 0);
if (bit1==1){
  b=((~b)+1);
}
printf("b: %02x",b);
```

this prints ffffff15. (%d prints -235).

Comment: `int b=(int)a;` - that is *not* how you convert two hexadecimal characters to an `int`. and `char a="ab"` should be flagging warnings. `"ab"` is a `char[3]`, not `char`.

Comment: I can't believe this actually compiles.

Comment: `char a` is character variable.  It has a space for just 1 char. Did it compile? (OO)

Comment: Need to see complete code.  `disp` is assigned to what value?

Comment: yikes, I was paraphrasing some parts  of my function to pare down to the twos complement stuff and messed some parts up. it's fixed now

Comment: `b` is holding just one byte.

Comment: then why does printing b add the 3 0xff bytes? Thanks for your help!

Comment: b is `int` type. This type usually occupies 4 bytes.  So for an example, lets say b = 15.  Hex representation is  0x0000000F.  If you compliment this, it will become 0xFFFFFFF0.

Comment: @78687: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

You did not post the complete code, but it appears `a` must be an `unsigned char` array or a `unsigned char` pointer, or a `char` array and the type `char` is unsigned on your platform. Casting `a[i]` as `(int)` does not change the value, and evaluates to `235`.

The formula `b=((~b)+1);` does not *extend the most significant bit*, but merely computes as `b = -b`. Hence the result `-235`.

To replicate to most significant bit, you could write:

```
b = (a[i] & 0xFF) | (-bit1 & ~0xFF);
```

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // a is a byte array
    unsigned char a[] = "0a\xeb";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof a; i++) {
        int b = (int)a[i];
        int s = (b & 0xFF) | ((b & 0x80) ? ~0xFF : 0);
        printf("a[%zd] = 0x%hhx, b: 0x%x, %d, s: 0x%x, %d\n",
               i, a[i], b, b, s, s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
a[0] = 0x30, b: 0x30, 48, s: 0x30, 48
a[1] = 0x61, b: 0x61, 97, s: 0x61, 97
a[2] = 0xeb, b: 0xeb, 235, s: 0xffffffeb, -21
a[3] = 0x0, b: 0x0, 0, s: 0x0, 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  How did the size of array became 4?  How does `\x` characters get evaluated in an array?

Comment: @Nguaial: the initializer is a string with 3 characters and a null terminator, hence 4 bytes. `\xeb` is an escape sequence, `\x` followed by 2 hexadecimal digits is interpreted as a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand the problem: "`eb` turns into `ffffff15`. When I printf this, it's -235, not -21".
So it seems that you expect `ffffff15` to represent `-21` in decimal, and this seems as if you had a (very common) misunderstanding in how negative integral values are represented: Making a number negative does not just set a single "negative" bit, but actually inverts all the bits (and adds `1`). Let's assume an 8 bit example:

```
1..0000001  -1..11111111
2..0000010  -2..11111110
3..0000011  -3..11111101
...
```

As you can see, making an integral number `int x` negative turns it actually into `INT_MAX - x + 1` (which is the same as `~x + 1`), not into `x | 0x800000`. In the other way round, `0xfffff15` represents `0xfffffff - 0xeb + 1`, which means `-235`, not `-21`.